# How can I see how many documents were written & handle errors correctly?

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-json, reactivemongo-play-json

From the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html) I can see that I should be able to use `WriteResult.ok`, `WriteResult.code` and `WriteResult.n` in order to understand errors and the number of updated documents but this isn't working. Here is a sample of what I'm doing (using reactiveMongoDB/Play JSON Collection Plugin):

```
   def updateOne(collName: String, id: BSONObjectID, q: Option[String] = None) = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request: Request[JsValue] =>

     val doc = request.body.as[JsObject]
     val idQueryJso = Json.obj("_id" -> id)
     val query = q match {
         case Some(_) => idQueryJso.deepMerge(Json.parse(q.get).as[JsObject])
         case None => idQueryJso
     }

     mongoRepo.update(collName)(query, doc, manyBool = false).map(result => writeResultStatus(result))
   }

   def writeResultStatus(writeResult: WriteResult): Result = {

     // NOT WORKING
     if(writeResult.ok) {
       if(writeResult.n > 0) Accepted else NotModified
     } else BadRequest

   }
```

Comment: "Isn't working" is not specific enough to get anyhelp. The field `n` is supported and unit tested.

Comment: @cchantep you can see in my code the example of what isn't working - meaning that it cannot be returned in a `Result` or trigger alternative actions. Yes - `WriteResult.n` can do this but `WriteResult.code` can only be outputted to screen which doesn't help to ensure specific error handling. I can definitely see the power & potential of ReactiveMongoDB but this is a big issue unless there is something that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Can I give an alternative approach here? You said:

> "in order to understand errors and the number of updated documents but this isn't working"

Why you don't use the logging functionality that Play provides? The general idea is that:

1. You set the logging level (e.g., only warning and errors, or errors, etc.).
2. You could use the `log` to output a message in any case, either something is ok, or it is not.
3. Play saves the logs of your application while it is running.
4. You the maintainer/developer could look into the logs to check if there is any errors.

This approach open a great possibility in the future: you could save the logs into a third-party service and put monitoring functionalities on the top of it.

Now if we look at the documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaLogging), you see about [different log levels](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaLogging#Log-levels), and [how to use the logger](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaLogging#The-default-Logger).

Comment: Thanks - that looks useful in general but I can't see how this can help to identify errors in mongo or any IO_